# Jenkins build for project with provided dependencies

Tags: jenkins, gradle

While I am building Gradle based project via Jenkins I'm getting compilation errors. It occurs because a have several jars in build.gradle file with scope 'provided'. I need this to do not include them into generated jar-file. How can I specify path or smth else to let project build on integration server?
Thanx in advance.

---

Listing of build file provided

```
    
configurations {
        provided
    }
    sourceSets {
        main {
            java { srcDir 'src/main/java' }
            resources { srcDir 'src/main/resources' }
            compileClasspath += configurations.provided
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        provided 'somelib1'
        provided 'somelib2'
        provided 'somelib3'
    }
```

Comment: Can you provide a stacktrace? Do you execute the same gradle commands locally as on Jenkins, and do they work? Do you have a `repositories {...}` block?

Comment: 2. Yes,  I have repositories block repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    mavenLocal()
}

Comment: I don't understand the question. Why do you think that you have to provide some additional Jars for the CI build (but not for the local build)? This is not what `provided` is about.

Comment: To build it locally I use scope testCompile and it's works fine. But I don't want include this jars into my project jar, so I use provided scope. In case of eclipse it's enough to include this jars to classpath, but for CI it does not works.

Comment: Is there any difference in how you invoke gradle locally versus on the Jenkins server? Unless these extra libs are not in any maven repository, your Jenkins server should be able to download them and also use them during the compilation.

Comment: Are you building a jar, war or ear?

Comment: I'm building single jar.

Comment: Other jar's are never included in your jar. So there is no reason not to list them as (test) compile time dependencies.

Comment: When I used 'compile' scope, all classes from those jars were also included into my jar, that is wrong for me. That's why I picked up approach with 'provided' scope.

Comment: Main idea of application is to provide possibility to end user put some sprcific jar (there is several options) and application will choose proper realization accordingly. That's why I don't want to store all possible jars in my single jar.

Comment: Could you post your entire build file then? Because normally classes aren't added to your jar from other jars, unless you've told gradle to do that...

Comment: My bad, root cause was java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space. I took warning about not found classes as root cause. After updating and restarting server all became fine.